# Javascript not working on wordpress after enqueue script in functions.php

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I want to add a javascript file but it is not working. I am using the Avada theme. I put this at the top of my functions.php document. I saved the but I do not see it in the source code on the page. I am trying to get the script to work on this page: `http://192.185.2.154/~sogo/tempsourceoneevents.com/exhibitor-services/build-a-booth/`

The code in functions.php

```
<?php

function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'custom-script',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bab.js',
        array( 'jquery' )
    );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
```

**The answer to my problem was in the comments by @adeneo, I needed to edit my javascript file**

"Nope, you can replace $(document).ready with jQuery(function($) { ... }); in Wordpress, that locks the value of the dollarsign in, so you can use the dollarsign inside that DOM ready function."

Comment: First of all you need to use `jQuery(function($) {...` to wrap the code as Wordpress is always in noConflict mode and doesn't recognize the dollarsign. Secondly, you need to wp_enqueue your script with jQuery as a dependency, and all of this is explained in the Wordpress Codex.

Comment: @Hitu Bansal its the directory of the site. The ip/directory/site name is the url to the site.

Comment: @adeneo would I still keep the "$(document).ready(function() {" and just put "jQuery(function($) {" before it and then end it in }? I have also enqueued the script following a youtube video. I changed my question but I do not see it in the source code to see if it worked.

Comment: Nope, you can replace `$(document).ready` with `jQuery(function($) { ... });` in Wordpress, that locks the value of the dollarsign in, so you can use the dollarsign inside that DOM ready function.

Answer (score -2):

Try this code..

You need to add jquery library first

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://192.185.2.154/~sogo/tempsourceoneevents.com/wp-content/uploads/bab.js"></script>
```